# JPA and JAXB annotations in the same class cause com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException

Tags: jpa, jaxb, annotations

I have 2 classes: Person and PersonAdapter. Person is generated from wsdl and cannot be changed.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Person")
public class Person {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    protected String name;

    // getters and setters
}
```

PersonAdapter is an object-adapter for Person and has some additional properties. Objects of this class are provided to clients of my service. I add all JPA and JAXB annotations to PersonAdapter class as I can't change Person class.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Person")
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PERSON")
public class PersonAdapter {

    private final Person person;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "name", required = true)
    @Column(name = "C_NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return person.getName();
    }

    @Column(name = "C_DESCRIPTION")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    // getters, setters, contructors
}
```

I can't annotate name property because it's in Person class, so I annotate getName method with both JAXB and JPA annotations. But such usage of these annotations on the same method/property causes IllegalAnnotationsException:

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 14 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
```

Is it possible to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Solved! The problem wasn't in conflict between JPA and JAXB annotations. The problem was in clash of JAXB contexts: `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` on `PersonAdapter` with public getter of `Person` provides access of my service's JAXB context to Person object from other context. And Person class is unknown for my context. I solved this problem replacing `XmlAccessType.FIELD` with `XmlAccessType.NONE`. Also it can be done with `@XmlTransient`.